# AppBarLayout disable drag on selected view

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

it's a known bug that if a AppBarLayout contains a scrollable view, scrolling this view will interfere with the AppBarLayout's scroll behavior.

Many answers on SO propose the following solution

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mAppBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = new AppBarLayout.Behavior();
behavior.setDragCallback(new AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback() {
       @Override
       public boolean canDrag(AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
            return false;
       }
});
params.setBehavior(behavior);
```

And this works well except for when there's another View inside the AppBarLayout that should be able to scroll the AppBarLayout.

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/custom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorAccent"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I want to be able to scroll the map (this works by returning false from canDrag) but still be able to collapse the layout when the custom_layout item is touched and moved upwards.

So i need something like

```
behavior.setDragCallback(new AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback() {
           @Override
           public boolean canDrag(AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
              if(mapIsScrolled)
                return false;
              else 
                return true;
           }
    });
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Hey, how did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Move this out of AppBarLayout:

```
<include layout="@layout/custom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorAccent"/>
```

Or if you really need that your layout is in the upper collapsing part, then add an touch listener to the layout (or try focus listener).

```
private boolean handleTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                canCollapse = true;
    }
    return false;
}


public boolean canDrag(AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
    if(canCollapse)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

Haven't tried it out yet, so you might have to make some additional tweeks.